# Loki configuration for S3 and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, grafana, grafana-loki

I am trying to connect Loki with AWS S3 and AWS DynamoDB but I am getting following errors:

```
level=error ts=2021-03-26T14:15:24.793276043Z caller=log.go:106 msg="error initializing bucket client" err="mkdir /data: permission denied"
level=error ts=2021-03-26T14:15:31.810902388Z caller=mapper.go:50 msg="unable to read rules directory" path=/tmp/loki/rules-temp err="open /tmp/loki/rules-temp: no such file or directory"
level=error ts=2021-03-26T14:15:51.847556802Z caller=table_manager.go:218 msg="error syncing tables" err="RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/\": dial tcp: lookup dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:35522->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout"
level=error ts=2021-03-26T14:17:41.859545187Z caller=flush.go:220 org_id=fake msg="failed to flush user" err="RequestCanceled: request context canceled\ncaused by: context deadline exceeded"
```

This is how my `/etc/loki/local-config.yaml` looks like.

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

ingester:
  wal:
    enabled: true
    dir: /tmp/wal
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 1h       
  max_chunk_age: 1h           
  chunk_target_size: 1048576  
  chunk_retain_period: 30s    
  max_transfer_retries: 0

schema_config:
  configs:
  - from: 2020-05-15
    store: aws
    object_store: s3
    schema: v11
    index:
      prefix: <table-name>

storage_config:
  aws:
    s3: s3://<access-key-id>:<secret-access-key>@<region>/<bucket-name>
    dynamodb:
      dynamodb_url: dynamodb://<access-key-id>:<secret-access-key>@<region>

compactor:
  working_directory: /tmp/loki/boltdb-shipper-compactor
  shared_store: filesystem

limits_config:
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h

chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0s
  index_tables_provisioning:
    enable_ondemand_throughput_mode: true
    enable_inactive_throughput_on_demand_mode: true
    provisioned_write_throughput: 0
    provisioned_read_throughput: 0
    inactive_write_throughput: 0
    inactive_read_throughput: 0
  chunk_tables_provisioning:
    enable_ondemand_throughput_mode: true
    enable_inactive_throughput_on_demand_mode: true
    provisioned_write_throughput: 0
    provisioned_read_throughput: 0
    inactive_write_throughput: 0
    inactive_read_throughput: 0

ruler:
  storage:
    type: local
    local:
      directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  rule_path: /tmp/loki/rules-temp
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  enable_api: true
```

Loki is inside docker-stack alongside with Grafana and Promtail. Stack is deployed via docker-compose file. Everything is running smoothly, just haven't got this in place yet.

As always, I have searched every corner of the internet and still have no clue. What am I missing?

Comment: can you share the corresponding docker-compose or respective stack configuration with docker images information

Comment: @samtoddler You can find docker-compose file here: https://gist.github.com/ipajumets/e58a7a1934942cb1708d2a000bf23f7d